# Replacing number+word in a list of alphanumeric elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have been struggling with this and I'd be glad if someone could help.
Starting from a string containing both words and number, what I want to do is find instances of the combination 'digit + the word 'minutes'' and replace it with ''only' + digit/2'.

"I run the marathon in **60 minutes**" --DESIRED OUTPUT--> "I run the marathon in **only 30 minutes**"

This should work with any other sentence containing instances of 'digit + the word 'minutes''.

What I have tried:

```
sent = "I run the marathon in 60 minutes" #example sentence, a string
sent_list = review.split() #convert to list

for i in range(len(sent_list)):
        if i.isdigit() and sent_list[i+1] == 'minutes': #find digits that are followed by 'minutes'
            sent_list[i] = i/2 #replace with its half
            sent_list.insert([i]-1,'only') #add only before the digit
```

I've tried other minor variations of this code but I am really stuck. This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the list using *i* as the loop counter. *i* will be a number in your case. What you want to do is

```
sent = "I run the marathon in 60 minutes"
sent_list = review.split() #convert to list

for i in range(len(sent_list)):
        if sent_list[i].isdigit() and sent_list[i+1] == 'minutes': #find digits that are followed by 'minutes'
            sent_list[i] = i/2 #replace with its half
            sent_list.insert([i]-1,'only') #add only before the digit
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also tried this before posting the question, but it won't work :/

Answer (score 0):

1. `sent_list = sent.split()` `review` doesn't exist, I believe you intended `sent`
2. `i.isdigit()` will try to check whether loop index is a digit or not. What you actually intend here is `sent_list[i].isdigit()`.
3. `sent_list[i] = int(sent_list[i]) // 2` this is how you will correctly get half of original value
4. You shouldn't insert elements into a list while iterating

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- You have a wrong variable reference `review`
- `i` is the index, not the word, so doing `i.isdigit()` is testing the wrong thing. And for the same reason: `i/2` is using the wrong thing. You want the word, not the index there.
- You should not go to the very last entry, as then `i+1` will be an index that does not exist in the list
- You don't want to insert "only" at `i-1`, but at `i`.
- Inserting a word, will mean that your next iteration will *revisit* the same word again, which will lead to a repetitive insertion of "only".
- At the end you end up with a list, not a string, so you still need to join the pieces back into a string

Taking those points into consideration:

```
sent_list = sent.split()

# Get both the index and the corresponding word. 
# + Exclude the last word.
# + Don't iterate the list itself, but a copy 
for i, word in enumerate(sent_list[:-1]):
    if word.isdigit() and sent_list[i+1] == 'minutes':
        sent_list[i] = str(int(word)//2)
        sent_list.insert(i,'only')

print(" ".join(sent_list))
```

You can also do this with a regular expression:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)(\s+minutes)", 
                lambda m: "only {}{}".format(int(m.group(1))//2, m.group(2)), 
                sent)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! not only this worked, but also made me understand where I went wrong. Thanks a lot for taking the time. :)

Answer (score -1):

Modify the code like this

```
sent = "I run the marathon in 60 minutes" 
sent_list = sent.split() 

for i in range(len(sent_list)):
        print("i",sent_list[i])
        if sent_list[i].isdigit() and sent_list[i+1] == 'minutes':
            n = int(sent_list[i])/2
            sent_list.remove(sent_list[i])           
            break
sent_list.insert(i,int(n))
sent_list.insert(i,'only')
print(sent_list)
```

Then convert the list to string

```
sent = " ".join(str(x) for x in sent_list)
```

Output:

```
I run the marathon in only 30 minutes'
```